# shell command on region with process substitution

Tags: process, shell-command, call-process

If I want to execute a shell command on a region I know I can use
`shell-command-on-region` via `M-|`, what if the command I want to
redirect my selection does not accept redirection to it's standard input.

In my case I would like to redirect my an active region to `python -m doctest`
In the shell I could use process substitution like `python -m doctest -v
<( echo '>>> print("hello")\nhello')`

Is there a direct way to that in emacs, or do I need to write some elisp
to get the active region and build the shell command myself?

---

update:

Not sure if this is a good solution and what will happen if the string contains quotes like `'`, but seems to work at the moment, I'll appreciate any suggestions.

```
(defun my/python/run-doctest-on-region ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((text-to-shell-cmd (if (use-region-p)
                                (buffer-substring-no-properties (region-beginning)
                                                                (region-end))
                              (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min)
                                                              (point-max))))
        (cmd (concat "python -m doctest -v <( echo '" text-to-shell-cmd
                      "')")))
    (shell-command cmd)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like the following with <kbd>M-|</kbd>:

```
cat > tmp.txt && python -m doctest -v tmp.txt
```

Comment: that makes sense, but this would create a `tmp.txt` file every time I run the command.

Comment: @Cesc That's right. It's up to you how to deal with the temporary file. Usually people put temporary files under `$TMPDIR`. You can delete the temporary file in the end of the command if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Building up on @xuchunyang answer.
Since the function I posted in the question was having problems dealing with single quotes in coda, I finally decided to modify the previous function, like so:

```
(defun my/python/run-doctest-on-region-or-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((tmp-file (concat (getenv "TMPDIR")
                          "tmp.txt"))
        (start (if (use-region-p)
                    (region-beginning)
                  (point-min)))
        (end (if (use-region-p)
                  (region-end)
                (point-max)))
        (buffer "*Python Doctest Output*")
        (command (s-join " "
                          (list "cat >" tmp-file "&& python -m doctest -v"
                                tmp-file))))
    (call-shell-region start end command nil buffer)
    (pop-to-buffer buffer)))
```

This way I don't need to type `cat > tmp.txt && python -m doctest -v tmp.txt` via `M-|`